# How to remove this bumpy/bad shading while not making the fender mesh more dent?

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

I am modeling a Z GT500 but at the joining corner at this mesh I get nasty shading that can be visible even in the game I am making it for:

[image]

The topology:
[image]

What I would like to avoid:
[image]

The rest of the topology looks questionable too but now I only want to concentrate on this specific part.

I include the .blend file if anyone wants to take a closer look:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eGJtVlSA-_AqZTcPmXxsHoSYjOZt3H-H/view?usp=sharing

Thank you in advance for your help!